# The action(s) 'Execute_stored_procedure (V2)' referenced by 'inputs' in action 'For_each' are not defined in the template

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-logic-apps

Getting this error when switching from Code to Designer view, even though there was no error on the design view at first.

Answer (score 0):

Code view was missing an underscore in the place of a space on the action name. After changing it to underscore _ it resolved the error